# how to use vkTemplate to populate html with JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-templates

I want to be able to take a php-supplied json object and put it into html. My old method of just making one incredibly long, incomprehensible string of html and then doing `$.append(hmltStr)` didn't go over so well on the last time I posted it about it on SO. I wonder if someone can explain to me how to put a json object into html using [this template](http://www.eslinstructor.net/vktemplate/) which is apparently an improvement of the [John Resign micro-template](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/).

Given the object:

```
{
"order": {
    "name": "TRADEMARK WHEEL COMPANY",
    "sales_order_id": "18278",
    "order_date": "05 \u2044 15 \u2044 2012",
    "due_date": "05 \u2044 21 \u2044 2012",
    "order_number": "1213140",
    "reference": "21192D\/35546",
    "order_description": "BICICLETTE",
    "ship_name": "ADAMS",
    "ship_address1": "1919 W RANDOLPH ST.",
    "ship_address2": "",
    "ship_city": "CHICAGO",
    "ship_state": "IL",
    "ship_postal_code": "60606",
    "ship_country": null,
    "ship_via": "FEDEX GROUND",
    "tracking_number": null,
    "package_contents": null,
    "freight": "0.00",
    "taxable": "0.00",
    "nontaxable": "748.88",
    "sales_tax": "0.00"
},
"line_item": [{
    "description": "RED ONE",
    "quantity": "2.00",
    "sell_price": "349.44"
},
{
    "description": "FRONT GEAR",
    "quantity": "2.00",
    "sell_price": "15.00"
},
{
    "description": "5th GEAR",
    "quantity": "2.00",
    "sell_price": "10.00"
}]
```

}

is the `data` being gathered by this ajax request, how can I populate an html table with it in the success part of this ajax function

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getJSON.php",
    data: submitStr,
    success: function (data) {

    //populate order details

    //loop through variable number of line items

}

<html>

<table id="contentTable">
</table>

</html>
```

Also, what is the `<script type="html/javascript></script>` tag. This may or may not be relevant, but I have seen it in templating; do I need to use that?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

a. include jQuery script, something like this:

```
<script src=".../libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

b. include vkTemplate plugin, something like this:

```
<script src="vktemplate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

c. in your html page add an element you want to inject this table, for example:

```
 <div id="container"></div>
```

**TEMPLATE**

(note, that line_item is array, so you to order and to line_item differently)

```
<table id="contentTable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            label-one:
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= o.order.name %> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            label-two:
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= o.line_item[0].description %> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

save this template ( for example as **order.tmpl** ) on your web server

**JAVASCRIPT**

initialize vkTemplate plugin and provide template URL as the first parameter, and json_data URL as the second parameter

```
$('#container').vkTemplate( 'order.tmpl', 'getJSON.php' );
```

---

At this point you're done.

Hope that helps

-Vadim

Comment: Hi Vadim, Thank you. That's incredibly helpful. Can I do normal javascript within the template file? `<%  var contents = shipment[i].package_contents;
                var tracking_number = shipment[i].tracking_number;
                var name = shipment[i].ship_name; if (contents){%> <%=contents%>; <%}%>` for example? thanks

Comment: Yes, you can. You can use regular javascript and manipulate with object within template.  Actually, you can consider <% ... %> as a closure.

Comment: right, but it seems that some javascript doesn't work within it. for example this, `<% if ( o.shipment ) } %> <span>test</span> <% } %>` gives me the error in the chrome console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier vktemplate.js line 66` and on that line is `return new Function("o", fn);` any ideas what this is about? thanks

Comment: there is a syntax error in your example: the first curly bracket must be '{'